# Where are my Frozen Synapse save files stored?

Tags: macos, frozen-synapse

In lieu of proper Steam Cloud support, I'm trying to set up Frozen Synapse to store its save files in Dropbox. What files or folders do I need to sync between my two (Mac) computers to achieve this?

(For bonus points: What about on Windows? Are the save files compatible between platforms?)

Comment: Most well written modern Mac games will put the saves in `~/Library/Application Support/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Steam version on Windows the files are in:

```
%SteamPath%\steamapps\common\frozen synapse\psychoff
```

In OS X, the files are in:

```
/Users/[Username]/Library/Application Support/FrozenSynapse/Psychoff
```

And are *all* the files beginning with `spSave` (I have three of this form).

<sup>Source - [FS Forum post answered by a Site Admin](http://forums.mode7games.com/viewtopic.php?t=2707)</sup>

I don't know if the files are cross-platform compatible.

Comment: I don't have FS installed, but the equivalent folder for the mac is /Users/{username}/Library/Application Support/Steam/SteamApps/

Comment: @Nick: On a Mac, that folder just contains the Frozen Synapse game executable (`Frozen Synapse.app`). The save data has its own folder in `Application Support`.

Comment: The correct Mac OS X path is `~/Library/Application Support/FrozenSynapse/Psychoff`

Answer (score 7):

On Linux, the saves are in `~/.local/share/FrozenSynapse/psychoff`.